# Sublime SFTP - cancel file download

Tags: sublimetext, sftp

How do you cancel the download of a remote file that is already in progress but appears to be non-responsive, without closing out of sublime all together and reopening the program?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ahh I found the answer according to sublime documentation. For OSX, the command is `ctrl+cmd+u+x`. Note, however, that this froze my session and I had to restart sublime, so beware!

Here's the [documentation page](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/usage)

Comment: That's weird. I've found this not to be working in the latest version on Sublime Text 3. Is anyone else having this problem? The shortcut just seems to do nothing and the command doesn't exist in the command palette (cmd+shift+p) while other ones like "SFTP : Monitor file - cmd+ctrl+u+m" can be found there.

Comment: I tried not working for me. Finally, stop downloading my remote files by closing the sublime window.

Comment: Same issue on mac.